# colors not being expanded in zsh print -P

Tags: zsh, colors

I have a zsh prompt script that uses `print -P` to perform prompt expansion. The script does not work properly on a particular remote system that I ssh into. The color directives in the  prompt print commands are not being expanded:

```
$ print -P '%F{blue}this should be blue'
{blue} this should be blue
```

Is there a way around this? I'm not sure why it should matter that I am using a remote system, since the display is happening through my local terminal emulator (iTerm2).

Comment: Which version of zsh (`echo $ZSH_VERSION`) are you using on this particular system? And does `print -P '%4Fthis should be blue' work better?

Comment: @Adaephon Thanks, your comment led me to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the version of `zsh` was 4.3.6. According to [the release notes](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/releases.html), the `%F` color expansion feature of the prompt was not added until 5.0 (though the release notes aren't 100% clear here-- in any case, `%F` doesn't show up in the 4.3.6 `zshmisc` manpage, which contains the prompt expansion documentation). Confusingly, the `%F` is still removed from the format string (apparently without doing anything)-- it's just the argument (the color name or number in braces) that is untouched. I was able to solve the problem by replacing `%F{color}` strings in my prompt format string with [ANSI escape codes](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) (e.g. `%F{blue}` becomes `\e[34m` and `%f`, which resets the color, becomes `\e[0m`).

Comment: FYI `%F` is present as early as 4.3.10, in line with the observation in the release notes that many differences between 4.2 and 5.0 were present in 4.3.17. My guess is that `%F` was introduced by 4.3.6, just not yet fully implemented.